# Замена данных по шаблону Java RegExp

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать замену подстроки в строк путем регулярных выражений?
В тексте (`html`) есть так называемые переменные по которым нужно делать замену - `%str%`. Я ищу при помощи `Matcher` все совпадения, нахожу. но вот как сделать что бы заменить это значение на нужное мне.

Код:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("%(\\w.*)%");

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(html);

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

        while (matcher.find()) {

        }
```

Comment: Что-то наподобие [этого](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37236219/3832970), да?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew да. проблема решилась.

Comment: Я добавил ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться методом [`Matcher#appendReplacement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement(java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String)), с помощью которого можно осуществлять замену динамически, на основе полученного совпадения.

Вот [примерный код](http://ideone.com/TGJK3E):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String s = "Код %здесь%, кот %там%";
        HashMap<String, String> h = new HashMap<String, String>();
        h.put("здесь" , "на земле");
        h.put("там" , "в раю");
        System.out.println(convertTree(s, h));
    }

    private static String convertTree(String s, HashMap<String, String> conv) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("%(\\p{L}+)%"); // Задаем шаблон
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);             // Инициализация Matcher
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();   // Буфер для конечного значения
        while (m.find()) {                          // Проверка на совпадение
            if (conv.containsKey(m.group(1))) {     // Проверка на наличие ключа
                m.appendReplacement(result, conv.get(m.group(1))); // Подставляем значение из HashMap
            }
            else { 
                m.appendReplacement(result, m.group(0));  // Или найденное совпадение, если ключ не найден
            }
        }
        m.appendTail(result);        // Добавить остаток строки
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```